# Net 6.0 Console App Signal R client keeps disconnecting direct after connection

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I newbe to Signal R Core here. i am try to connect to a Signal R  client to A Serverless hub. In my example for now i just want to create multiple instances of en get a connection every time a new one is connected.

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client   = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:7071/api/negotiate?userid=1");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var    responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var    d            = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseBody);
        string urlString    = Convert.ToString(d.Url);
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    // Set the log level of signalr stuffs
                    logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug);
                })
                .WithUrl(urlString, options => options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(Convert.ToString(d.AccessToken)))
            .Build();
        
        connection.On<NewConnection>("newConnection", c => OnReceiveMessage(c));

        await connection.StartAsync(); 

     //    while (connection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
     //   {
     //   }

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void OnReceiveMessage(NewConnection connection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"user {connection.UserId} with connctionid {connection.ConnectionId} has been connected");
    }
```

On my Javascript client this is working but on my Net client it keeps disconnecting everytime right after connection:

```
[2022-10-02T11:03:27.542Z] Executing 'Functions.OnConnected' (Reason='(null)', Id=3878244a-50cd-47a6-b8c6-98ed1c0dd5c6)
    [2022-10-02T11:03:27.544Z] KimOo3chMz6M9zxEPAlpzQ has connected
    [2022-10-02T11:03:27.549Z] Executed 'Functions.OnConnected' (Succeeded, Id=3878244a-50cd-47a6-b8c6-98ed1c0dd5c6, Duration=7ms)
    [2022-10-02T11:03:27.571Z] Executing 'Functions.OnDisconnected' (Reason='(null)', Id=693bec34-3ed3-434c-93fb-e366c1113e4a)
    [2022-10-02T11:03:27.572Z] KimOo3chMz6M9zxEPAlpzQ has disconnected
```

Not sure what i am missing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. This behavior was cause by the fact that websockets are not supported by default in Net-Core console app. by changing this to longpolling this as solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).